# Not all html tags get stored with ckeditor in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ckeditor

I'm use ckeditor in my laravel project. My problem is not all html tags are inserted to my database.

This is example my source html in ckeditor :
`<h1><font face="courier new, courier, monospace"><strong>this value of textarea</strong></font></h1>`

When I click submit, only `<strong>this value of textarea</strong>` inserted to my database.

The output when I print_r(Input::all()); :

```
Array
(
    [_token] => xVqWzYv0WK9w7xLJjcDHW6kCQARCChaGzVM9usbU
    [title] => test title
    [summary] => <h1><font face="courier new, courier, monospace"><strong>this value of textarea</strong></font></h1>
    [category] => 20
)
```

This is my code:

```
$post = $this->question->getById($id);
if ( ! $this->validator->validEdit(Input::all()))
{
  return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($this->validator->errors());
}
$post = $this->question->edit($post, Input::all());
```

Comment: Can you share the code of your edit method?. I guess, it's the one that adds the returned data to to the database. Make sure you use PDO or try the php $post->summary = mysql_real_escape_string($post->summary) .

Comment: everything looks fine with cod, maybe you mess up something else ?

Comment: Check your `Length/Values` in database.

Answer (score 1):

Put this line in your customConfig.js

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```

You can read more about allowed content rules  [here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules)